# Android WebView not loading cached website when internet is off

Tags: android, caching, webview

I am trying to load the cached version of the website when mobile internet is off. But I am only getting a white screen.

Here is my code.

```
binding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    binding.webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    binding.webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    binding.webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    binding.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    binding.webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());

    if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
        binding.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }

    binding.webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    binding.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            binding.webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    });
    binding.webView.loadUrl("website url here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:
`binding.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);`
To:
`binding.webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);`

Comment: It is not working. Same issue white screen when the internet is off.

Comment: Put a break point on the line `getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()` and make sure it doesn't return null